# How to search files with specific pattern on os x

Tags: macos, search, regex, finder, file-filter

I'm looking for a way to search a huge folder of images, and select only the file names that ends with a pattern like: 800x600.jpg or 645x321.jpg etc'

There must be some raw search command for the finder search for that.
Regex-based...

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Is `grep` not available in osx?!

Comment: It is, but I have no idea how to use all these grep/regex commands...

Answer (score 2):

This is an example that I just tested - this should give you a filtered list of all files that have the pattern of 3 digits followed by an x followed by 3 digits and then the extension of `jpg`.

```
ls | egrep "\d{3}x\d{3}\.jpg"
```

Similarly in general you can list all files in a directory (in the `Terminal.app` of course) using the `ls` command, and then use the pipe (`|`) to pass the list of files to `grep` or `egrep`. I like using `egrep` because it has a nicer syntax for regular expressions. You can also achieve the same effect by using `grep -E`. Both are already available on OS X. Good luck!

Comment: I have tested and it works on a folder, but doesn't scan all sub folders.
Also, since it's terminal command, how can I select and delete the found results ?
Thansk

Comment: Most UNIX commands have an optional `recursive` flag which will help you scan all the sub folders.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Ambidextrous's answer, with the extra bits you've asked for in the comments:

`ls | egrep -r "\d{3}x\d{3}\.jpg" | xargs rm`

**Warning** This will delete everything it matches, I would recommend you copy the entire folder you want this to work on, then run the above command in that directory to look at the results.

*If you want to delete all without a prompt for each file, add the `-f` flag after `xargs rm`*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a "super user" enough answer, but I use a free program called easyFind. Which can be found here : www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html